# Getting back the .txt as a type in the explorer's New context menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

My Windows 10 install doesn't seem to support .txt files in the New context menu.

Using the traditional *ShellNew* regedit hack works perfectly for other filetypes, and I've been able to create **.bat** option. For some unknown reason, something goes wrong when I try the same thing for **.txt**.

I tried the following **.reg**:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

Checking on regedit, the ShellNew key was created, as well as the NullFile string value. Only no option shows for them.

I also tried to create a ".text" filetype, for investigation purposes, with this:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.text]
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.text\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

It didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run DISM and SFC and restart.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.   dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup      dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image /restorehealth   SFC /SCANNOW    Restart and test.

Comment: How many additional  file types have you added.  There is a maximum  umber you can add and I suspect you have reached that number

Comment: @John Thanks for the idea. It indeed found "corrupt" stuff, but ultimately it didn't do any good for the txt filetype thing.

Comment: @Ramhound for now, I've only created the .bat ShellNew and the .text one.

Comment: So at this point, do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation link. Start with the option to Keep Everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything. 

You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing.